# Delete old records on Heroku (Rails 3.1) via rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, heroku

I can't seem to delete old records from my app on heroku.

Currently the heroku scheduler runs:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.get_data
  # this populates my app but the database is starting to get large and I don't need the old records
  scr = Scrape.new
  data_array = scr.scrape
  store_data(data_array)
  # destroy_old_data
end
```

but I'd like to uncomment the "destory_old_data" call.

```
def destroy_old_data
  # oldest = Post.where("updated_at > ?", 30.days.ago)
  # Post.delete_all("updated_at > ?", 30.days.ago)
  # Post.destroy_all("updated_at > ?", 30.days.ago)
  oldest = Post.find(:all, "updated_at > ?", 30.days.ago)
  oldest.destroy
end
```

As you can see, I've tried a few things that seem to work locally in the console but I can't get them to work on heroku.

The errors I'm getting are like:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

or

when using Post.find
NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for #<Array:0x00000004579898>
```

What is the easiest call I can make to find and remove all these old records successfully?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting that error on the `oldest = Post.find(:all, "updated_at"...)`?

Comment: No, for that I get: NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for #<Array:0x00000004579898>

Comment: "oldest" is an array of records. You would need to iterate through them to destroy each one, right?

Comment: Ha, that makes sense. Is there any specific call I can use to just destroy all those records without needing to iterate over the records?

Comment: Checkout http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all

Comment: the only consideration with delete_all is that it doesn't instantiate and invoke callbacks. If the OP's model has_many Comments and they should be deleted, this won't do it, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address the **NoMethodError**, you need to iterate through the array of records and call `destroy` on each one.

```
oldest.each { |r| r.destroy }
```

or you could use a method like `destroy_all` where you don't even need to do an extra `find`. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class

```
Post.destroy_all(['updated_at < ?', 30.days.ago])
```

Putting the conditions inside of an array should solve the **ArgumentError** as @luke-chadwick mentioned in his answer.

One item to consider with this is how many records you are deleting (here's a note from the docs):

> Note: Instantiation, callback execution, and deletion of each record can be time consuming when you’re removing many records at once. It generates at least one SQL DELETE query per record (or possibly more, to enforce your callbacks). If you want to delete many rows quickly, without concern for their associations or callbacks, use delete_all instead.

`delete_all` may be a faster option for you unless you need to clean up other associated records as well, like Comments.

Comment: Just to point out an error: The `>` operator shouldn't be used, as it would make ActiveRecord destroy data _newer than_ 30 days old. Use `<` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying a "delete" on an array, a list of posts. You should call a delete on each item in that list instead.

```
Post.where(["updated_at > ?", 30.days.ago]).each do |post|
  post.delete
end
```

Where, takes one argument. And returns a list of Posts that match its criteria. You can then loop over these posts and perform an action (`delete`) on each.

Comment: this returned an empty array(meaning: => []). i have posts older than 30 days. doing a Post.first returns a record with an updated_at: "2011-12-23 19:01:53"

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is will only return posts created 30 days ago, not all posts older than 30 days.

Comment: You are correct, I copy-pasted wrong code from the question. Updated to make the query return `greater then 30 days ago`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Post.destroy_all` method takes anything that can be passed to the conditions parameter of find(:all). This includes a string, hash or an array.

If you show the source in the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class) for destroy all you should see this:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 879
def destroy_all(conditions = nil)
  find(:all, :conditions => conditions).each { |object| object.destroy }
end
```

As you can see, it takes a single argument. So the conditions need to be wrapped in array braces (as shown):

```
Post.destroy_all(['updated_at > ?', 30.days.ago])
```